# SVN Server, set user to only access a branch

Tags: svn

We use [SVN Server from CollabNet](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/getit.html) and we have a new fellow working with us and I had to create a user/pwd to him...

no problem here.

Question is, How can I make sure that this new user had only access to one branch and not the full SVN structure, not even read permissions, just Read/Write on that branch?

Thank you.

We used to use [VisualSVN](http://www.VisualSVN.com) Server but the GUI does not allow me to set users only to access a folder (branch) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used Apache HTTP and SVN (either http or https access), you could do this with [authz](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir).